# How to solve app:fastforward_increment and app:rewind_increment not found in new exo player library?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

How can i add fastforward_increment in my ExoPlayer programatically in new Version ! Now . While using this  app:rewind_increment and  app:fastforward_increment in xml it's throwing error that it doesn't found !

Can anyone help me !

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6):

From `2.15.0` release notes: 
Remove `rewind_increment` and `fastforward_increment` attributes from
`PlayerControlView` and `StyledPlayerControlView`. These increments can
be customized by configuring the `Player` (see `setSeekBackIncrementMs`
and `setSeekForwardIncrementMs` in `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`), or by
using a `ForwardingPlayer` that overrides `getSeekBackIncrement`,
`seekBack`, `getSeekForwardIncrement` and `seekForward`. The rewind and
fast forward buttons can be disabled by using a `ForwardingPlayer` that
removes `COMMAND_SEEK_BACK` and `COMMAND_SEEK_FORWARD` from the
available commands.

Create the player instance as usual using `ExoPlayer.Builder` and then wrap it with `ForwardingPlayer` and set to your `PlayerView` or `StyledPlayerView`:

```
  final ExoPlayer exo = new ExoPlayer.Builder(/* context= */ this)
      .setRenderersFactory(renderersFactory)
      .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
      .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
      .build();
  ForwardingPlayer player = new ForwardingPlayer(exo) {
    @Override
    public long getSeekBackIncrement() {
      return 10 * 1000; // 10 sec
    }

    @Override
    public long getSeekForwardIncrement() {
      return 10 * 1000; // 10 sec
    }
  };
  playerView.setPlayer(player);
```

Comment: hii brother ,can u plzz provide me a sample code ?

Answer (score 6):

Just saw that, it's simple with 2.17:

```
 val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000)
        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000)
        .build()
```